How to create synchronized Plotly subplots with fixed node positions in a network graph and cumulative time-series data in a line plot?
I'm trying to build a synchronized visualization using Plotly with two subplots: a network graph below and a line plot above. Each node in the network graph represents an entity in a fixed 2D space, with its color intensity indicating its activation level, which varies over time. The line plot shows the activation levels over time for each node. I want to use a slider to control both subplots simultaneously.
The requirements for each subplot are:

Network Graph (Bottom Subplot):

Each node represents an entity at a fixed position in 2D space (x and y coordinates are constant).
The color intensity of each node indicates its activation level, which changes over time.
Moving the slider should update only the color intensity of each node based on the selected time.


Line Plot (Top Subplot):

Shows each node's activation level over time, with the x-axis representing time and the y-axis representing activation levels.
Each node has a constant color in the line plot.
As the slider moves, the line plot should accumulate data up to the selected time, effectively showing the activation history up to that point.



Here's my code and an image of the plot so far, which sets up the two subplots and attempts to control them with a slider. However, I'm running into the issue that the network graph nodes (the subplot below) do not stay in fixed positions; instead, the x-axis also updates here.

import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import numpy as np

# Example activation levels
times = np.arange(0, 10, 0.5)
nodes = ['A', 'B', 'C']
activation_data = {
    'A': np.sin(times),
    'B': np.cos(times),
    'C': np.sin(times + np.pi / 4)
}

# Define fixed colors for each node
node_colors = {
    'A': 'red',
    'B': 'blue',
    'C': 'green'
}

# Create subplot layout with 2 rows: line plot (row 1) and network graph (row 2)
fig = make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1, shared_xaxes=True, row_heights=[0.5, 0.5], vertical_spacing=0.15)

# Add line plot traces for each node with constant color, one scatter per time step
line_traces = {node: [] for node in nodes}
for node in nodes:
    for t in range(len(times)):
        trace = go.Scatter(
            x=times[:t+1],  # Show data only up to the current time
            y=activation_data[node][:t+1],
            mode='lines+markers',
            name=f'Node {node} Activation',
            line=dict(color=node_colors[node]),  # Apply constant color for each node
            visible=(t == 0)  # Initially only the first point is visible
        )
        fig.add_trace(trace, row=1, col=1)
        line_traces[node].append(trace)

# Add network graph traces, one for each time step
for t in range(len(times)):
    node_activation_colors = [activation_data[node][t] for node in nodes]
    fig.add_trace(
        go.Scatter(
            x=[1, 2, 3],  # Replace with actual node positions
            y=[1, 2, 3],
            mode='markers',
            marker=dict(size=20, color=node_activation_colors, colorscale='Viridis', showscale=False),  # Remove color scale
            name=f"Network at t={times[t]:.1f}",
            visible=(t == 0)  # Only first frame visible initially
        ),
        row=2, col=1
    )

# Define the slider steps
steps = []
for t in range(len(times)):
    step = dict(
        method="update",
        args=[{"visible": [False] * len(fig.data)}],
        label=f"t = {times[t]:.1f}",
    )
    # Make all traces up to the current time `t` visible for the line plot (row 1)
    for node_idx, node in enumerate(nodes):
        for i in range(t + 1):
            step["args"][0]["visible"][node_idx * len(times) + i] = True

    # Enable only the current network graph trace in row 2
    step["args"][0]["visible"][len(nodes) * len(times) + t] = True
    steps.append(step)

# Add slider to control both plots
sliders = [dict(
    active=0,
    currentvalue={"prefix": "Time: "},
    pad={"t": 50},
    steps=steps
)]

# Update layout to remove legend and add slider
fig.update_layout(
    sliders=sliders,
    height=600,
    title="Synchronized Network Graph and Line Plot with Time Slider",
    showlegend=False  # Disable legend
)

fig.show()

The problems with this implementation are:

Fixed Positions in Network Graph: How can I ensure the x and y positions of nodes in the network graph remain constant while only the color updates based on activation at each time step?
Cumulative Data in Line Plot: How can I make the line plot accumulate data up to the selected time on the slider, so it shows the full activation history up to that point?


I found solutions to both of my problems, and I'd like to share them in case others face similar issues.

Problem 1:

Fixed Positions in Network Graph Issue: The nodes in the network graph were not staying in fixed positions because Plotly automatically adjusts the axis ranges based on the visible data. When the data updates, the axes rescale themselves.

Solution: Set fixed axis ranges for the network graph subplot using update_xaxes and update_yaxes with fixedrange=True and specify the range parameter.



Problem 2:

Cumulative Data in Line Plot
Issue: I was initially creating multiple traces per node for each time step, which made controlling visibility complicated and didn't allow the line plot to accumulate data up to the selected time.

Solution: Create a single trace per node in the line plot and use Plotly's frames and animation features to update the data over time. In each frame, update the x and y data of the line plot traces to include data up to the selected time.




Updated Code
Here's the updated code that implements these solutions:
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import numpy as np

# Example activation levels
times = np.arange(0, 10, 0.5)
nodes = ['A', 'B', 'C']
activation_data = {
    'A': np.sin(times),
    'B': np.cos(times),
    'C': np.sin(times + np.pi / 4)
}

# Define fixed colors for each node
node_colors = {
    'A': 'red',
    'B': 'blue',
    'C': 'green'
}

# Node positions
node_positions = {
    'A': (1, 1),
    'B': (2, 2),
    'C': (3, 1.5)
}
x_positions = [node_positions[node][0] for node in nodes]
y_positions = [node_positions[node][1] for node in nodes]

# Create subplot layout
fig = make_subplots(
    rows=2, cols=1,
    shared_xaxes=False,
    row_heights=[0.5, 0.5],
    vertical_spacing=0.15
)

# Add line plot traces for each node
for node in nodes:
    fig.add_trace(
        go.Scatter(
            x=[],  # Empty initial data
            y=[],
            mode='lines+markers',
            name=f'Node {node} Activation',
            line=dict(color=node_colors[node]),
        ),
        row=1, col=1
    )

# Add network graph trace
initial_colors = [activation_data[node][0] for node in nodes]
fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        x=x_positions,
        y=y_positions,
        mode='markers',
        marker=dict(
            size=20,
            color=initial_colors,
            colorscale='Viridis',
            showscale=False
        ),
        name="Network Graph",
    ),
    row=2, col=1
)

# Fix axes ranges for network graph
fig.update_xaxes(
    range=[0, 4],
    fixedrange=True,
    row=2, col=1
)
fig.update_yaxes(
    range=[0, 3],
    fixedrange=True,
    row=2, col=1
)

# Create frames for animation
frames = []
for t, time in enumerate(times):
    frame_data = []
    # Update line plot traces
    for i, node in enumerate(nodes):
        x_data = times[:t+1]
        y_data = activation_data[node][:t+1]
        frame_data.append(go.Scatter(
            x=x_data,
            y=y_data,
            mode='lines+markers',
            line=dict(color=node_colors[node])
        ))
    # Update network graph colors
    node_activation_colors = [activation_data[node][t] for node in nodes]
    frame_data.append(go.Scatter(
        x=x_positions,
        y=y_positions,
        mode='markers',
        marker=dict(
            size=20,
            color=node_activation_colors,
            colorscale='Viridis',
            showscale=False
        )
    ))
    frames.append(go.Frame(data=frame_data, name=str(t)))

# Define slider steps
sliders = [dict(
    steps=[
        dict(
            method='animate',
            args=(
                [str(k)],
                dict(
                    mode='immediate',
                    frame=dict(duration=0, redraw=True),
                    transition=dict(duration=0)
                )
            ),
            label=f"t={times[k]:.1f}"
        ) for k in range(len(times))
    ],
    transition=dict(duration=0),
    x=0, y=0,
    currentvalue=dict(
        font=dict(size=12),
        prefix='Time: ',
        visible=True,
        xanchor='center'
    ),
    len=1.0
)]

# Update layout with frames and slider
fig.update(frames=frames)
fig.update_layout(
    sliders=sliders,
    height=600,
    title="Synchronized Network Graph and Line Plot with Time Slider",
)

# Fix axes ranges for line plot
fig.update_xaxes(
    range=[times[0], times[-1]],
    row=1, col=1
)

fig.show()

